# FreeTDS error in PHP: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: php, odbc, archlinux, freetds

I have to connect to a MSSQL server from Arch Linux with ODBC.
I use FreeTDS, and with isql, it's working:

isql sqlexpress dev Dev

But not in PHP.
I use PHP in interactive mode:

---

```
PHP > $conn = odbc_connect("sqlexpress", 'dev', 'Dev');
PHP > $a=odbc_exec($conn, 'SELECT * FROM measures;');
PHP Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x00 is unknown., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in php shell code on line 1

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x00 is unknown., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in php shell code on line 1
```

---

I've searched a lot, but I can't find any solution (or even somebody with the same problem).
My config files:

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[sqlexpress] 
Server = 192.168.10.39
Port = 1433
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = capture
UserName = dev
Password = Dev
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS driver
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/libtdsS.so
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/freetds.log
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount = 1
```

Have a nice day!
Mate

Comment: Hello! I try to run this: $a=odbc_exec($conn, 'select 1 as test_col;');
But it faild with the same error, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my working configuration files for connecting to a MSSQL database from Ubuntu:

/etc/odbc.ini

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[ebe]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = my_database
ServerName              = my_server_name
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1

# Change the "no" to "yes" to enable ODBC logging.
[ODBC]
Trace           = no
TraceFile       = /tmp/odbc.log
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[global]
        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
[my_server_name]
    host = my_server_domain_or_ip
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

And finally, here's my PHP connection string:

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO("dblib:dbname=my_database;host=my_server_domain_or_ip", 'username', 'password');
```

I believe setting the tds version to 8.0 could be a big help to you.